# getting same image after filtering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, convolution

I am implementing a match filter for fingerprint pores but as a output I am getting the input image..but actually I should get the pore of fingerprint image..here is the equation which I am implementing..

[image]

here Po is the pore model for theta = 0 radians and Ptheta is the pore model for any value of theta.
sigma is scale factor...and here ismy code

```
for i1 = 1:40:240
        for j1 = 1:40:320
            t = floor(1/F(i1,j1));
            sigma = floor(t/12);

            i = -floor(3*sigma);
            j = floor(3*sigma);
            O = theta(i1,j1);
            blk_im = im(i1:i1+40-1,j1:j1+40-1);
            [x,y] = meshgrid(-(sigma):(sigma));

            if O <= 0
                P = exp((-j^2/2*sigma^2).*cos((pi/3*sigma)*i));
            else   
                i_bar = x.*cos(O)-y.*sin(O);
                j_bar = x.*sin(O)+y.*cos(O);

                P = exp((-(j_bar.^2)/(2*sigma^2)).*cos((pi/3*sigma).*i_bar));
                P_MAP(i1:i1+w-1,j1:j1+w-1) = conv2(blk_im,P,'same');

            end

        end;
    end;
            figure;
            subplot(1,2,1);imshow(im,[]);title('input image');
            subplot(1,2,2);imshow(P_MAP,[]);title('pore filter');
```

here theta is orientation value in radians and F is frequency..
my output
[image]

what to do in order to get the correct output ...thanks in advance

Comment: What are your values of `theta`? The whole if-else bit is superfluous really, since equation (2) is the generalised case of equation (1) you can just use it in all cases (i.e. if `O==0`, then `i_bar==i` and `j_bar==j` anyway). Or is it intentional that you're not assigning to `P_MAP` if `O<=0` (in which case why bother calculating `P` there either?)

Comment: theta is a matrix containing the orientation angle at each pixels in radians..theta values lies between 0 and 3.12 radians...and about P..it was my way of defining the for loop for theta < 0..thanks for your valuable suggestions..but still getting the input image as output image..what to do..

Comment: The images look different to me. There may be a problem in the way you're defining `P`, that you convolve with the image to get your output.  I suggest you put some debug stops in and see what it looks like.

Comment: @nkjt .OK I'll try to debug the program using stop points to check for error..buy the way I am using conv2 function for convolving the image.Is it good or should I search for some different method for convolving images..